# How to convert excel time field from hours (1:00) and half hours (0:50) to get totals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some data containing 'total hours' in the following format:

- 1:00
- 1:50
- 8:75

where:

- 1:00 = 1hr
- 1:50 = 1hr 30mins
- 8:75 = 8hrs 45mins

I'd like to work out the total number of hours, but I am not sure what calculation to use (or what work needs to be done to get the data into a usable state)

- Currently the cells containing the data are formatted as 'custom' and the type is h:mm
- The data was exported from a web application

[image: screenshot]

[here is a link to an example of the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2yyy0hu2gyfsa3/excel_time_issue.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Something like =LEFT(A2,len(A2)-3)) + RIGHT(A2,2)/100 would give you the time as a value, eg, 8.75 as a number instead of 8:75 as a string.  Then total the column

Comment: @Vityata the cell is formatted as 'custom' and the type is h:mm

Comment: @falter - with "custom" and "h:mm" I get `9:15` when I write `8:75`... Are you sure?

Comment: @Vityata screenshot added for clarity

Comment: @falter - so, when you write `8:75` does it stay like `8:75` or is it changed to `9:15`?

Comment: @Vityata - yes, if I enter the data manually then I get the same result as you. however this data is exported from a web application

Comment: @falter - so if it is exported from a web application to a custom column with `h:mm` format then the result should be the same, I guess?

Comment: @Vityata the data is exported *from* a web application into excel - the data is correct in excel (it only changes when you enter new data manually which I do not want to do)

Comment: @falter - I meant "from", but the question stays. You export `8:75` to a column formatted as `h:mm` and it stays `8:75`?

Comment: Something like: `=TIME(MID(A1,1,FIND(":",A1)-1),(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,2)/100)*60,0)` if you allow the data to go into a text cell first... You may need to implement some rounding if the times don't always fall exactly on a minute

Comment: @Vityata yes that is correct

Comment: @falter - what happens if you click on `Calculate` on the Excel Ribbon>Formulas? Would it change to `9:15` then?

Comment: @RichardTompsett this results in #VALUE!

Comment: @Vityata nothing appears to happen after pressing 'calculate now' from the Formulas ribbon

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you make a snapshot of value where it displays `8:75` (or minutes above 59) and where it also shows the actual value from the formula bar? Something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9953.png

Comment: @falter - what would happen if you close and open the Excel file?

Comment: In your sample file, the format is, indeed `h:mm`.  **HOWEVER** the actual stored values are **TEXT**, and not "real time values".  If, in this data, `1:50` represents `1 1/2` hours, what does `1:30` represent?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of comments, but I'm going to go out on a limb and assume we can treat the value in A2 as text.  To get the hours portion:

Step 1:  Select the column that has the times and change the format to Text.
Step 2: Select the column that will have your calculations and set the format to General

```
 =VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1))
```

The minutes portion

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))/100*60
```

And as a decimal number of hours where the original 8:50 becomes 8.5 (8 hours 30 minutes)

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)-1))+VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))/100
```

If the original text is a format where 8:30 means 8 hours, 30 minutes:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A7,FIND(":",A2)-1))+VALUE(RIGHT(A2,2))/60
```

Comment: i've uploaded an example of my data in a file

Comment: your data file only has :00 and :30 for the minutes portion.  I would interpret :30 as half an hour.  Are you sure when you say :75 should be 45 minutes?